# What happens when you return a value with or "||" operator?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm not trying to get or want anything from this code. I just have a confusion with a part of the following code. The author has returned a value with or `||` operator. my question is which value will be returned and when?

```
function findSolution (target) {
    function find (current, history) {
        if (current == target) {
            return history
        }else if (current > target) {
            return null
        } else {
            return find (current + 5, `${history} + 5)`) ||
                    find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`)
        }
    }
    return find(1, '1')
}

console.log(findSolution(24))
```

here is the part of the code is bothering me

```
return find (current + 5, `${history} + 5)`) ||
       find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`)
```

can anyone please tell me, which value when return? and why?

Comment: If the left hand side is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it is returned, otherwise the right hand side is returned.

Comment: `expr1 || expr2` ["If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr1; else, returns expr2."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: @NicholasTower thank you! pardon me for my stupidity. my real confusion was that,  here truthy or falsy how will be determined? I mean suppose  ``` find (current + 5, `${history} + 5)`) ``` when it turn into false?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you! pardon me for my stupidity. my real confusion was that here truthy or falsy how will be determined? I mean suppose ``` find (current + 5, ${history} + 5)) ``` when it turn into false?

Comment: @kabirsumn `return null` branch is falsy. You could read about falsy values here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy. Also nothing to worry about we all were beginners once.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment):

> If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr1; else, returns expr2.

in other words, you can see it as a function like this:

```
const or = (fel, sel) =>{
     if(fel) return fel;
     return sel;
}
```

That's why this happens:

```
const x = 0 || 1; // x == 1
// same as:
//
// const or = (fel, sel) =>{
//      if(fel) return fel;
//      return sel;
// }
// const x = or(0,1)
```